# Div height doesnt match with responsive background image

Tags: html, css, height, background-image, responsive-images

I have a background image of hawaii and i want each radio button to be exactly where the island is and when the window gets smaller i want everything to be responsive but i have a problem.The height of the div doesnt get smaller when the image gets smaller only the width so the radio buttons dont have the correct height.I have tried many things but i cannot figure this out.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="divmap">
    <input type="radio" name="island" value="Niihaou" id="Niihaou" required/>
    <input type="radio" name="island" value="Kauai" id="Kauai" required/>
    <input type="radio" name="island" value="Oahou" id="Oahou" required/>
    <input type="radio" name="island" value="Molokai" id="Molokai" required/>
    <input type="radio" name="island" value="Lanai" id="Lanai" required/>
    <input type="radio" name="island" value="Maui" id="Maui" required/>
    <input type="radio" name="island" value="Kahoolawe" id="Kahoolawe" required/>
    <input type="radio" name="island" value="Hawaii" id="Hawaii" required/>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.divmap{    
background: url(http://travelquaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/maps-directions-hawaii-resort-rentals.jpg)  no-repeat ;
background-size: contain;
width: 700px;
height: 400px;
border: 1px solid red;
max-width: 100%;
}
#Niihaou{
position: relative;
left: 40%;
top:20%;
}
```

You can see the size of the div because i used a border and i want it to always be the same height with the background image.I want a solution in HTML/CSS only because of the project. 
This is my first question on stackoverflow so if i do something wrong please tell me.

Comment: I don't understand if you want the height of div to change or stay the same?

Comment: @RachelS i want it to change when the image gets smaller.